# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, gnupg, openpgp

when I perform **sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum** this gives me an errors like,

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpy4v562r0/pubring.gpg' created gpg:

/tmp/tmpy4v562r0/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created gpg: key

1C52189C923F6CA9: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ethereum" imported

gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg: imported: 1

**gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.**
```

I tried many ways to solved but no luck.Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the Ethereum repository first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt update
```

Remove imported GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key del 2A518C819BE37D2C2031944D1C52189C923F6CA9
```

Import GPG key of the Ethereum repo again:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2A518C819BE37D2C2031944D1C52189C923F6CA9
```

Add repository again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt update
```

**UPDATE**

Remove the Ethereum repository again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt update
```

Remove imported GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key del 2A518C819BE37D2C2031944D1C52189C923F6CA9
```

Try

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2a518c819be37d2c2031944d1c52189c923f6ca9
```

and next

```
gpg --export --armor 2a518c819be37d2c2031944d1c52189c923f6ca9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add repository for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
echo -e "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ethereum-ubuntu-ethereum-xenial.list
```

Update apt:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install software you want from the Ethereum repository.

Comment: I tried your steps but after 
"sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum" gives me an error like 
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpjj0_soy7/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpjj0_soy7/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 1C52189C923F6CA9: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ethereum" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

Comment: means no need to hit **sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum** command ?